# Matching English words algorithm stops working when using Ruby bang methods

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I am writing a matching algorithm that checks a user-entered word against a huge list of english words to see how many matches it can find. Everything works, except I have two lines of code that are essentially meant to not pick the same letters twice, and they make the whole thing just return a single letter. Here is what I've done:

```
word_array = []

File.open("wordsEn.txt").each do |line|
    word_array << line.chomp
end

puts "Please enter a string of characters with no spaces:"
user_string = gets.chomp.downcase

user_string_array = user_string.split("")

matching_words = []

word_array.each do |word|
    one_array = word.split("")

    tmp_user_string_array = user_string_array

    letter_counter = 0

    for i in 0...word.length
        if tmp_user_string_array.include? one_array[i]
            letter_counter += 1

            string_index = tmp_user_string_array.index(one_array[i])
            tmp_user_string_array.slice!(string_index)
        end
    end

    if letter_counter == word.length
        matching_words << word
    end
end

puts matching_words
```

This part here is what breaks it:

```
string_index = tmp_user_string_array.index(one_array[i])
tmp_user_string_array.slice!(string_index)
```

Can anyone see an issue here? It all makes sense to me.

Comment: Does it help if you change `tmp_user_string_array = user_string_array` to `tmp_user_string_array = user_string_array.dup` perhaps? Currently both variables refer to the same array by reference, so you're effectively slicing both arrays. The `dup` should fix that.

Comment: Actually that really helps a lot Henrik, thank you very much!

Comment: Not an answer, so I'm throwing this in as a comment - it would probably be much faster and would certainly require a **lot** less code to store the words in a [`Set`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) (see [`include?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-include-3F)) rather than an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what's happening. You're eliminating letters for non-matching words, which prevents matching words from being found.

For example, take this word list:

```
ant
bear
cat
dog
emu
```

And this input to your program:

```
catdog
```

The first word you look for is `ant`, which causes the `a` and `t` to be sliced out of `catdog`, leaving `cdog`. Now the word `cat` can no longer be found.

The cure is to make sure that your `tmp_user_string_array` really is a temporary array. Currently it's a reference to the original `user_string_array`, which means that you're destructively modifying the user input. You should make a copy of it before you start slicing and dicing.

Once you've got that working, you might like to think about more efficient approaches that don't require duplicating and slicing arrays. Consider this: what if you were to sort each word of your lexicon as well as the input string before starting to look for a match? This would turn the word `cat` into `act` and the input `acatdog` into `aacdgot`. Do you see how you could traverse the sorted word and the sorted input in search of a match without the need to do any slicing?

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is great! I appreciate the detail you put into your answer.